# Excel Application on Time method doesn't work properly

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I would like to automatize scheduled report on my company. I found out a method called Application OnTime in Excel, which after some reading looks like a perfect match.

The task is following, on chosen periods during day I would like to import data through powerquery and then save a file. I would like to work it all the time. My simple code looks like that:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("06:30:00"), "Module1.MyMacro"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("09:30:00"), "Module1.MyMacro"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("12:00:00"), "Module1.MyMacro"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("14:29:00"), "Module1.MyMacro"
End Sub



Sub MyMacro()
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:05:00"))
ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Due to overlong refresh of the data I gave extra 5 mins before saving file. However I encountered problem, after some time my script stops working. I have tried different solutions from the Internet, unfortunately I couldn't complete the task on my own.

I have a request If someone could tell me abaout what I've forgotten and explain the issue.

Comment: "after some time my script stops working" - how long is "some time" ?

Comment: its probably the workbook hasn't done refreshing in 5 min. when you save a workbook that is refreshing... the refresh gets cancellled. i'd recommend turn off `background refreshing`, and use `DoEvents` to solve this. Even better, you can build a custom class to handle `On QeuryRefresh` to let you decide what to do next after queries are refreshed without having excel to be halted while refreshing.

Comment: @TimWilliams I have been checking progress on wednesday, thursday and friday and everything was fine and at the beginning of the next week I noticed that ultimate version was saved with friday date.

Comment: @Rosetta
I have turned off background refreshing but it didn't help, I am going to learn more about DoEvents then, because I have never used it before.

Comment: Is it supposed to run over multiple days?  You only set 4 OnTime, and after they've run once they will not run again...

Comment: @TimWilliams, Yes, I would like to work it everyday

Comment: If you want a more-stable, long-term approach, then using the Windows Task Scheduler is probably a better solution here. Eg see https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/how-to-automatically-run-excel-vba-macros-daily or https://www.superexcelvba.com/en/tutorial/034-scheduled-execution

Comment: @TimWilliams I am not sure if this tool is possible to use in our company, I will check after holiday. If it is not, there is still possible by usage of VBA?

Comment: Task Scheduler is part of Windows and the most reliable way to do what you want.  If you still want to use OnTime, then you need to schedule the next run each time `MyMacro` fires.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter is *EarliestTime*. Your post lack some detail, but I guess it'll start a bit late. The third parameter is *LatestTime*. Try something like this:

```
Application.OnTime TimeValue("06:30:00"), "Module1.MyMacro", TimeValue("06:40:00")
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.ontime

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. Still After one day it stopped working

Comment: How are you scheduling the next run? OnTime jobs run once.